# javascript href clears IE page

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have the following html.
when I click on the link in IE it dumps the return value on an empty page.
in chrome it simply runs the function without touching the page.
Can something be done to make IE behave like chrome in this respect?

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function foo(){
  return true;
}
</script>
<a title="call foo" href="javascript:foo()">return true</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of a `javascript:` scheme URL is that it runs some code, which generates some data, which the browser then navigates to.

If you just want to run some JS when something is clicked: Don't use a link.

Use the right tool for the job.

```js
function foo(){
  return true;
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", foo);
```

```html
<button title="call foo">return true</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function foo(){
  event.preventDefault();
  return true;
}
</script>
<a title="call foo" href="javascript:foo()">return true</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the event.preventDefault() method to prevent hyperlink default event in the click event. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function foo(e) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ////get the href attribute.   
        //var href = document.getElementById("btn").getAttribute("href");
        ////display the page. You could also using "window.open(href)" to open a new tab to display the page.
        //window.location = href;
        return true;
    }
</script>
<a title="call foo" id="btn" href="https://www.google.com/" onclick="foo(this);">return true</a>
```